# Is there any undecidable language that is countable?

Tags: formal-languages, undecidability, uncountability

All we know is that if a language is countable than it must be recognizable. However, a recognizable language may or may not be decidable.

Comment: $\Sigma^*$, the set of all words, is countable. Therefore, *every* language is countable. It is certainly **not** the case that every countable language is recognizable.

Comment: Every language *whose alphabet is finite* is countable. Check also this answer: http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/12665/30527.

Comment: @AndréSouzaLemos ​ : ​ ​ ​ Even languages with countably-infinite alphabets are countable. ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @Shaull Make an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Your premise is incorrect. The set of all words, $\Sigma^*$, is countable (as long as the alphabet is countable, and we usually refer to finite alphabets anyway).

Every language is a subset of $\Sigma^*$, and thus every language is countable. In particular, there are undecidable and unrecognizable languages.